# Regex to find the image name inside the img tag

Tags: php, regex

Today, the expression verifies that if the ALT tag of the empty image is empty, it is filled with what is in the Replace variable.

But basically what I want is in the substitute variable to put the name of the image, that name of the image as seen in the output is in this pattern here.

http://dominio.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/amazon-prime-channels.jpg

Since the url, date and file name and extension varies

```
<?php

$content = 'Conteudo alt=""<img loading="lazy" class="aligncenter wp-image-71444 size-medium lazyloaded" src="http://idinheiro.local/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/amazon-prime-channels-300x225.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="225" sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px" srcset="http://idinheiro.local/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/amazon-prime-channels-300x225.jpg 300w, http://idinheiro.local/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/amazon-prime-channels-768x576.jpg 768w, http://idinheiro.local/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/amazon-prime-channels-554x416.jpg 554w, http://idinheiro.local/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/amazon-prime-channels.jpg 960w" data-ll-status="loaded">';

$pattern = '~(<img.*? alt=")("[^>]*>)~i';

$replace = '$1Here should be the name of the image$2';

$content = preg_replace( $pattern, $replace, $content );

echo $content;

?>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/OKsLfm/1) to grab the `src` attribute value. This demonstrates how:

```
<?php

// Your content.
$content = 'Conteudo alt=""<img loading="lazy" class="aligncenter wp-image-71444 size-medium lazyloaded" src="http://idinheiro.local/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/amazon-prime-channels-300x225.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="225" sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px" srcset="http://idinheiro.local/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/amazon-prime-channels-300x225.jpg 300w, http://idinheiro.local/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/amazon-prime-channels-768x576.jpg 768w, http://idinheiro.local/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/amazon-prime-channels-554x416.jpg 554w, http://idinheiro.local/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/amazon-prime-channels.jpg 960w" data-ll-status="loaded">';

// https://regex101.com/r/OKsLfm/1/
preg_match('/\<img(?:.+?)src="([^"]+)/', $content, $matches);
$imageUrl = $matches[1];

var_dump($imageUrl); // http://idinheiro.local/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/amazon-prime-channels-300x225.jpg
```

**UPDATE**

To get the original filename before any scaling is done, you can do this:

```
<?php

// Scaled image is saved with -<width>x<height> suffix.
$filename = 'amazon-prime-channels-300x225.jpg';

// Get rid of extension first.
$basename = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_FILENAME);

// strrpos() finds the position of the last occurring string '-'.
// Use substr() to grab everything from the start of the string (0) up to (exclusive!) the position
// of the last dash.
$origBasename = substr($basename, 0, strrpos($basename, '-'));

var_dump($origBasename); // string(21) "amazon-prime-channels"
```

Comment: Excellent, but in this case I just wanted to get the name of the file which is the final string of the src url, how do I do it?

Comment: You mean the last source specified in the `srcset` attribute?

Comment: no, in this case it is inside the same src, but only the name of the file, src:

http: //idinheiro.local/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/amazon-prime-channels-300x225.jpg

and in this example I want to extract only the file name amazon-prime-channels.jpg

Comment: Use `basename($imageUrl);` for that.

Comment: It is true! But I ended up using pathinfo to remove the file extension. One more question: The output is now amazon-prime-channels-300x225, how do I remove the -300x255? In this case, only amazon-prime-channels would remain. Remembering that this numbering also varies.